# How to properly maneuver through the values in a class in python?

Tags: python, html, django, class

I'm trying to display an object in html. 
The object is a digit ranging from 1 to 10 (from now on called "mood") and was previously recorded in models.py. The mood is connected to a different class called "day" through models.ForeignKey.

In views.py I recall both "day" and "mood", that was previously recorded, so that the html page can be rendered with the appropriate day info and appropriate mood value for that day.

Currently when I do that, instead of displaying a digit from 1 to 10, I get this " < Query Set [ < Mood: 7>]> " instead.

```py
views.py

def day(request, day_id):
    # show all data for the day
    day = Day.objects.get(id=day_id)
    mood = day.mood_set.order_by('mood')
    context = {'day': day, 'mood': mood}
    return render(request, 'mood_collector/day.html', context)
```

```py
models.py 

class Mood_Morning(models.Model):
    day = models.ForeignKey(
    Day,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    mood = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=0.0)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%d' % self.mood
```

```html
<p> Day: {{day}} </p>
<p> Mood: {{mood}}</p>
```

I expect the output to be " Mood: (insert digit 1-10) "
instead I get " Mood: < QuerySet [< Mood: 7>]> "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mood` is a `QuerySet` of `Mood_Morning`s, not a single one. Indeed, for a given `Day`, there can be zero, one or more `Mood_Morning`s related to that `Day`.

You can for example iterate over the moods, and then render these individually, like:

```
def day(request, day_id):
    # show all data for the day
    day = Day.objects.get(id=day_id)
    moods = day.mood_set.order_by('mood')
    context = {'day': day, 'moods': moods}
    return render(request, 'mood_collector/day.html', context)
```

Then in the template we can render this as:

```
{% for mood in moods %}
    <p> Mood: {{mood}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

If however for a given `Day` object there can be at most one `Mood_Morning` object, you should consider using a [**`OneToOneField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField).

Comment: It worked! Thanks!
Is there any way I could simplify this and make it so there only can be one mood per day? Which would cancel the need to make a for loop?

Comment: @kinimod: yes, as said at the bottom, you might want to alter your design, and use a `OneToOneField` instead.